# Complete metric space (using measurable applications)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ nonempty bounded set. We define the following space
$$X=\{u, \,\, u:[0,1] \rightarrow U, \,\, u \text{ is measurable}\}$$
With the metric : $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $d(u_1,u_2)=||u_2-u_1||_{L^1([0,1])}$.

Since $\forall u \in X$, we have $u \in L^{\infty}([0,1])$,hence $u \in L^1([0,1])$.

Then can we deduce that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space? (since $L^1([0,1])$ is complete).

Comment: @Crostul look again

Comment: The metric $d$ seems not to be well defined. That's because $L^1$ norm is defined for functions whose codomain is $\Bbb R$, while the codomain of $u$ is $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Crostul I think OP is writing $L^{1}([0,1]$ for $L^{1}([0,1];\mathbb R^{n})$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $d$ is not a metric unless you identify functions which are equal almost everywhere.

Even if this is done there is no hope of completeness unless $U$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{n}$. Take a sequence $(x_i)$ in $U$ converging to  a point $x $ not in $U$. Let $u_k(t)=x_k$ for all $t$. Then $(u_n)$ is Cauchy but it is not convergent.

Suppose $U$ is closed. Let $(u_k)$ be  a Cauchy sequence. By completeness of $L^{1}$ there exists an integrable function $u$ such that $\int_0^{1}\|u_k-u\| \to 0$. We only have to show that $u(t) \in U$ for almost all $t$. There exists  a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ converging a.e. to $u$. Hence $u(t)=\lim u_{n_k}(t) \in U$ for almost all $t$.

Comment: that's the problem we will have only convergence of a subsequence, say $(u_{n(k)})_k$, so it does not directly mean that the space is complete.

Comment: and If we assume that $U$ is closed, how do we deduce that u that the sequence is convergent (while we only have the convergence of a subsequence)

Comment: @AnasLW I have included a proof.